# scala playframework: create list of Json.Reads/Writes from list of classes

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a large list of cases classes to be used in request / response handling. I'd like to avoid explicitly declaring Json.reads/writes for each class.

Is something like this possible?

```
Seq(classOf[CaseClassOne], classOf[CaseClassTwo])
.map(clazz => Json.reads[clazz])
```

Comment: I guess you would like to have the `Reads` instances available implicitly anywhere, don't you?

Comment: I think Shapeless can accomplish that